# How is the formula $R=l^2/6h+h/2$ for calculation radius of curvature of a spherical surface is derived?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geometry, instrument

The problem with the derivation is that in one figure the point M is taken the bisector of AB while in the second one it is completely out of the line AB.
So **for AM.MB=OM.MZ to be true the chords AB and OZ should lie in the same plane.**
AB and OZ are parts of two different circle.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which part of the given derivation do you not understand?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert The part where AM.MB=OM.MZ  because in the sphere AB and OZ are chords of different circles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about                                 ?

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your solution Penguino. The only problem with our solutions is that we are working on circular sections whereas the article deals with a tripod with a center measuring probe measuring a sphere. I will be removing my solution soon.

Comment: So what? Diagram 3-3 shows the simple relationship between  $l$ and $r$  in the plane of the three points of the legs of the spherometer, so given the relationship above, it is trivial to reexpress  $R$ in terms of $l$.

Answer (score 2):

See if you like this better than the method in your book...

Apply Pythagoras's theorem to triangle AME in the left hand diagram, obtaining an equation relating $R,r$ and $h$.

Express $r$ in terms of $l$ using half of triangle AMB in the right hand diagram.

Re-arrange, making $R$ the subject. It does work. Good luck!